# How to print text in color without the termcolor module in python

Tags: python

I would just like to know how could I print color text without the termcolor module.
I don't want the termcolor because if someone use my script and he don't have the termcolor module installed, it won't work! :(
I read somewhere that I could just use the code here: http://www.tux-planet.fr/les-codes-de-couleurs-en-bash/

with print.
But I just cant get it work.

Comment: It's not unheard of to publish dependencies for users of your programs...

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print the escape sequences.  For example, to print 'foo' in red, try out this one:

`print '\x1b[31mfoo\x1b[0m'`

To discover the escape sequences, you can use `termcolor.colored` function.

But, the "normal" way is to simply have a dependency on `termcolor`.. you can give them the module at the same time as you give them your script!